# Getting "NoMethodError" when trying to sort my Ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, field

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I'm having difficulty sorting an array based on a particular field of the objects stored in that array.  I have

```
    results.sort! { |a,b| 
      puts "a time: #{a.time_in_ms} b time: #{b.time_in_ms}" 
      a.time_in_ms < b.time_in_ms
    }
```

and although I have verified that both fields are integers in my rails console, I get a "" error when I run this code ...

```
a time: 16968700 b time: 21784000 
NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for true:TrueClass
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/text_table_to_race_time_converter_service.rb:668:in `sort'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/text_table_to_race_time_converter_service.rb:668:in `populate_overall_rank_info'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/text_table_to_race_time_converter_service.rb:408:in `get_data_hash'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/text_table_to_race_time_converter_service.rb:25:in `get_race_times'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/active_com_service.rb:57:in `process_page_data'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_import_service.rb:88:in `process_race_data'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How do I sort based on a field in my object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these

```
results.sort_by(&:time_in_ms)
```

Of in the long-form

```
results.sort { |a, b| a.time_in_ms <=> b.time_in_ms }
```

The `sort` method expects the block to return an integer value rather than a boolean. You get this error because your block returns a boolean.

Quoting from the `ri` documentation

> Returns an array containing the items in enum sorted, either according to their own `<=>` method, or by using the results of the supplied block. The block should return `-1`, `0`, or `+1` depending on the comparison between a and b.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 results.sort_by! { |element| element.time_in_ms }
```